# Integrating Scribe On-Premise with Microsoft AX 2009 On-Premise

Tags: axapta, scribe-workbench

I want to integrate Microsoft AX 2009 via Scribe Insight. I have installed both on Virtual Machine(on-premise). 
While making a connection, it asks for AX endpoint URL but I am not able to find it in AX. Is there a way to find that URL or for integration?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should configure your endpoint or ask support Microsoft they will give the right answer but make sure to use the right Adapater